# JS array find() that returns something other than the found element

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

Here's some code that runs each value in the array against an `expensiveOperation` function, and returns the first one that meets some criteria.

```
let result = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].find(value => {
  let newValue = expensiveOperation(value)
  return meetsCritera(newValue)
}
result = expensiveOperation(result)
```

But what's returned from the `find` function is the array value (e.g. `3`), rather than the result of `expensiveOperation(3)`. To get that final value, I need to run `expensiveOperation` once more outside the body of `find`.

How can I avoid running it once more and return the desired value from `find`. Is there another ES6 array function that would let me do this?

Comment: your just returning the condition true or false not the value

Comment: assign the value to a variable which has scope outside the function....

Answer (score 4):

You can always use a good old loop:

```
let result;
for (let value of [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) {
  let newValue = expensiveOperation(value);
  if (meetsCritera(newValue)) {
    result = newValue;
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and exit the loop if the criteria is met.

```js
var expensiveOperation = a => 3 * a,
    meetsCritera = v => v > 10,
    result = (() => {
        var newValue;
        return [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].some(value => {
            newValue = expensiveOperation(value);
            return meetsCritera(newValue);
        }) && newValue;
    })();

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: You'll need a variable scoped in the callback to `.some()`. Otherwise, even if a value never passes `meetsCriteria()`, the `newValue` will be the last result of `expensiveOperation`

Comment: Sorry, the `&&` as flow control threw me off. It would've been `false` instead, so I was mistaken. IMO, logical operators as flow control doesn't make for clear code.

Comment: i could wrap it in a classical if clause.

Comment: It's just a nitpick. Using `.some()` is a good idea here. Gave you my +1 for this.

Answer (score 1):

This is a decent usecase for `.reduce`.

```
let result = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].reduce((result, value) => {
  if (result) return result;

  let newValue = expensiveOperation(value)
  if (meetsCritera(newValue)) return newValue;
}, null);
```

Comment: you can not exit reduce early.

Comment: @NinaScholz The question never asked for exiting early, it asked to make it not execute `expensiveOperation` on the ones after `meetsCritera(newValue) === true`, which this achieves nicely.

Comment: I think the OP *did* hint at this with the name *expensiveOperation*, and the question *"How can I avoid running it once more?"*.

Comment: While it does avoid the `expensiveOperation` (assuming `newValue` will always be truthy), avoiding the extra iteration would be good. This doesn't feel like a traditional use case for a fold operation, where the result is the accumulation of having visited each member.